How to specify multiple search criteria with the emcli list command?
The below code returns the desired result set.
emcli list -resource="Targets" \
-bind="TargetType='oracle_database'" \
-columns="TARGET_NAME:20,TARGET_TYPE:20" \
-search="TARGET_TYPE='oracle_database'"

The below code works as well.
emcli list -resource="Targets" \
-bind="TargetType='oracle_database'" \
-columns="TARGET_NAME:20,TARGET_TYPE:20" \
-search="TARGET_TYPE='oracle_pdb'"

But the below code returns 0 rows (which is incorrect)
emcli list -resource="Targets" \
-bind="TargetType='oracle_database'" \
-columns="TARGET_NAME:20,TARGET_TYPE:20" \
-search="TARGET_TYPE='oracle_database'" \
-search="TARGET_TYPE='oracle_pdb'"

BTW, I have also tried the following. But the below code fetches more than the database targets.
-search="TARGET_TYPE like'oracle_%'"

Can someone please suggest how I can fold the two search criteria into one ?
Thanks in advance.
FR

I don't think it's possible. The multiple search arguments act as separate filters, presumably intended for different criteria, so they AND rather than OR. You could try "TARGET_TYPE like'oracle_%d%b%'" to restrict your second try, but it still won't be just those targets; but you mihgt be able to filter the output. Otherwise you probably have to run both list commands and combine the results yourself.

Hi Alex, Thanks for the reply. While your solution works, but it still fetches some undesirable data. Thus, I have decided to do away with the native filters and explicitly use the grep command as follows.

emcli list -resource="Targets" 
-bind="TargetType='oracle_database'" 
-columns="TARGET_NAME:20,TARGET_TYPE:20" | grep -e 'oracle_database' -e 'oracle_pdb'
